# How to make a SQL request ordered by amount of true conditions

Tags: sql, request, conditional-statements

Imagine I have 10 conditions in my 'WHERE' clausule of a 'SELECT' request.

I need only to show the results that satisfied at least 5 of the conditions, and ordered by the amount of satisfied conditions: 10,9,8...

How can I do this posible?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Would probably be useful sharing the query you have and which SQL you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may vary slightly based on which DBMS you're using, but for MS-SQL, the WHERE clause could be segmented into separate CASE statements that are then summed and sorted:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN (CONDITION 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN (CONDITION 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    (...)
    + CASE WHEN (CONDITION 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchCount
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MatchCount DESC
```

You can then wrap this as a sub-query to get the results matching at least 5:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN (CONDITION 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN (CONDITION 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        (...)
        + CASE WHEN (CONDITION 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchCount
    FROM MyTable) T
WHERE T.MatchCount >= 5
ORDER BY MatchCount DESC
```